# How do I get podcasts onto an iPod Nano in macOS Monterey?

Tags: mac, sync, ipod, podcasts

I can download episodes in Apple Podcasts.

I can connect the iPod nano (4th gen, cable only, no internet) and use Finder to open sync settings. The manual podcasts selection shows the feeds, but none of the new episodes.

When I hit Sync, I get an error popup `Some items, including “<...>”, were not copied to the iPod “<my> iPod” because they could not be found.`

How do I get it to sync the new episodes?

---

The history is a bit complicated. The ipod was working fine with an older MacOS and iTunes, but the computer finally died. I got a new macbook and restored from time machine. Initially, it was updating new episodes, but there were two entries for each feed in the Podcasts app, and on the ipod each episode appeared twice - or sometimes more, they seemed to breeding. So I started removing one of the feeds, sometimes both and resubscribing. Now I can download new episodes in the podcasts app, (but it won't download new ones for me), but they don't appear in the ipod sync settings.

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer:

Manually copying files into the old itunes podocasts folder will get file onto the device; the ipod will sort them into shows.

This still stinks for getting new episodes and removing played episodes, especially since you can't really tell from the garbage filenames which is which.

Apple podcasts folder:

`~/Library/Group Containers/243LU875E5.groups.com.apple.podcasts/Library/Cache`

iTunes media folder:

`~/Music/iTunes/iTunes Media/Podcasts/Unknown Podcast`

In theory I could break them out into folders other than `Unknown Podcast`, but limited information is available. Some have cover images, and some have data if I enable the Author/Title fields in the finder columns. Others are mysteries.